# Eclipse Graphical Layout does not load images

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I created a custom class that extends View, and put some custom drawing routines into it.  When the class initializes, it creates a Bitmap using:

```
Bitmap template = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.template);
```

This works fine when I run the application both in the AVD, and on a native device, but in Eclipse, I get a null-reference exception any time I try to call

```
canvas.drawBitmap(template, srcRect, destRect, null);
```

if I wrap the drawBitmap statement in an if-check for template == null, then the graphical layout shows, and the view is blank on screen (which is to be expected if I am not drawing the background).

I started noticing a while ago, that when I added and removed images to my "drawable-hdpi" directory, that the images in the graphical editor were starting to get corrupted.  Recently, I just cleared out all the old test graphics I was using, so the only images in the drawable-hdpi directory are "ic_launcher.png" and "template.png"

Does anyone know how I can reset Eclipse so that it will start reading the graphics properly again?

Comment: I have updated both the android SDK, and Eclipse through their respective automated update systems, and rebooted my computer, and now I'm not seeing null-ref exceptions anymore, BUT, I am seeing that the sprite graphic I'm using is not rendering all sprites, only a small subset.  This may just be a limitation of Eclipse not being able to draw subsets of bitmaps in the graphical editing mode, but any further input on this from anyone would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Click Projects then press Clean. This should refresh your .xml and R class

Comment: Thanks.  I ran the clean, but it doesn't appear to have fixed the issue.  I still see a null reference exception when trying to edit the layout graphically.